# Firefox on Mac: Top suggestion in address bar

Tags: macos, firefox, address-bar

On both Chrome and Safari, when typing in the address bar, I get shown suggestions from history and bookmarks. The best result is entered in the address bar for **autocompletion**. I would only have to press <kbd>↩</kbd> to start the loading the website:

[image]

In Firefox this is not the case, I first have to manually use the <kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>-keys to select the suggestion and then hit enter:

[image]

Can I change this behavior in Firefox to be consistent with Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter about:config in the adressbar and then set browser.urlbar.autofill to true. I still find it enoying though that you have to type "www." first.

Edit: I found this extension which does exactly what you want called [Enter Selects](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/enter-selects/)

Answer (score 1):

In most apps you can use control-n or p (next/previous) to move "down" a line. It works in safari, but not sure about firefox.

Not a perfect solution but at least it keeps your hands on the keyboard, instead of straying out to the extended area. Remapping caps-lock to control helps too.